# Android background service or UI

Tags: java, android

I want to know the trick apps like Viber/Whatsapp/Tango uses to keep running.

I mean when I press back button several times, still when I go back to Viber or Whatsapp, UI is same as I left, it doesn't terminate.

Also when I receive a message, it runs again and already has my new message in it's UI. How it works? How can I do that?

I did my research, if I register a service, I would have a service to check for incoming messages from server, but my UI will terminate if user presses back button.
Other method I saw was overriding back button, but what if user presses home button or even power button to lock phone? 
Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
still when I go back to Viber or Whatsapp, UI is same as I left, it doesn't terminate.
```

They use [SharedPreferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) to save the current state where you left of, of the `activity/fragment` so when you quit from your app it will save your Activity's state `(let say you are currently at second activity)` as an Integer 2 to the SharedPreferences, by the time you go back again from your app it will grab that data that was saved from your SharedPreferences and load Second Activity again.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, how about receiving incoming messages?

Comment: @user3404070 see the link I give above it is a tutorial on how to use SharedPreferences, and for the incoming message use Service on that.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice the link, sorry. So in service, you mean they keep a live TCP connection all the time so when there is new message, then receive it?

Comment: @user3404070 yes you are right. Service is used for long running task such as socket's TCP

Comment: are you sure about long TCP session? I mean, seriously, whatsapp and viber and tango, all of them which are installed in my phone, each of them have a live TCP session to their server ALL the time even when my phone is in locked state?

Comment: He said such as.  More likely they wake up ever 2 or 3 minutes and ping the server with an HTTP request.

Comment: @user3404070 Have you heard about GCM before, that what they are using a push notification service more like a live socket connection to the server, Also tcp connection is not costly in bandwith when you are only taking string characters from the server and waiting for response from the client.